# RPython ord() with non-ascii character

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, pypy, rpython

I'm making a virtual machine in RPython using PyPy. My problem is, that I am converting each character into the numerical representation. For example, converting the letter "a" provides this result, 97. And then I convert the 97 to hex, so I get: 0x61.

So for example, I'm trying to convert the letter "á" into the hexadecimal representation which should be: 0xe1 but instead I get 0xc3 0xa1

Is there a specific encoding I need to use? Currently I'm using UTF-8.

--UPDATE--

Where instr is `"á"`, (including the quotes)

```
for char in instr:
    char = str(int(ord(char)))
    char = hex(int(char))
    char = char[2:]
    print char # Prints 22 C3 A1 22, 22 is each of the quotes
    # The desired output is 22 E1 22
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-

char = 'á'

print str(int(ord(char)))
print hex(int(char))
print char.decode('latin-1')
```

Gives me:

```
225
0xe1
0xe1
```

Comment: That hasn't fixed it, I still get "C3 A1" instead of "E1". Thanks for helping though!

Comment: Can you post the snippet of code you are using to print the hex value?  I get 0xe1.

Comment: I added the code to the question. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @user3566150 I updated my answer.  I read somewhere that this may be processor-dependent

Comment: So is it my computer then? I'm using a Mac. When I run your code it says "TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 2 found"

Comment: I believe so, because I just ran your script you posted and I got
22
e1
22.
Try to run on a different environment and see if you get different results.

Answer (score 0):

You are using version 2 of Python language therefore your string: `"á"` is a byte string, and its contents depend on the encoding of your source file. If the encoding is UTF-8, they are `C3 A1` - the string contains two bytes.

If you want to convert it to Unicode codepoints (aka characters), or UTF-16 codepoints (depending on your Python installation), convert it to `unicode` first, for example using `.decode('utf-8')`.

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

def stuff(instr):
  for char in instr:
    char = str(int(ord(char)))
    char = hex(int(char))
    # I'd replace those two lines above with char = hex(ord(char))
    char = char[2:]
    print char 

stuff("á")
print("-------")
stuff(u"á")
```

Outputs:

```
c3
a1
-------
e1
```