# Get ASCII Int with ord() of German umlaute (ÄÜÖ) in python

Tags: python, ascii, ordinals

Got some issues with `ord()` command and Unicode.

I want the decimal number of the entered ASCII letters.

For Example:

`ord('ÄÖÜ')` brings me these values: **[195, 132, 195, 150, 195, 156]**

- [195,132] = Ä
- [195,150] = Ö
- [195,156] = Ü

This is what i want:

- [196] = Ä
- [214] = Ö
- [220] = Ü

Any clues ?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23271542/rpython-ord-with-non-ascii-character) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342000/how-to-make-the-python-interpreter-correctly-handle-non-ascii-characters-in-stri) may help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
>>> [ord(i) for i in unicode('ÄÖÜ','utf-8')]
[196, 214, 220]
```

Answer (score 3):

You want the Unicode code points, not the bytes in the UTF-8 encoding:

```
>>> mystring = u'ÄÖÜ'
>>> [ord(c) for c in mystring]
[196, 214, 220]
```

Comment: This might work if my string is placed in python itself, the string it placed in a variable, but this might work as well, thanks a lot :)

Comment: The only difference between my answer and Robert's is the use of a Unicode literal versus a call to `unicode`; both produce the same Unicode object, subject to the default character encoding. (In my answer, the Unicode literal uses whatever character encoding is in effect; in Robert's the string literal passed as the first argument must UTF-8, or the second argument is wrong.)

Comment: Ahh i see, can i use that unicode literal on variables too?

Comment: Of course. All information is stored with the value itself; the "variable" is simply a name bound to the value.

Comment: yeah i know, but how does this look like? something like that u'mystring' ? i guess this wont work because its in string quotation marks then.

Comment: How are you getting the string?

Comment: Sorry, forgot about that thread ;-)  doesnt matter anyway cause it works like mentioned above :-) Thanks alot